# Correct way to use Bootstrap4 with gulp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gulp, bootstrap-4

I just wonder, what is the correct way to use Bootstrap 4 scss with gulp?

Here's my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'scss/app.scss'
    ])
        .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
        .pipe(CleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});
```

Then app.scss looks this way:

```
// Import full bs4 after custom overriden variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

bootstrap.scss itself imports all bs modules.

Is this the "right way"?

Or should i compile bs scss files without importing it in my app.scss:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("css"))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way is to copy your assets outside of `node_modules` because backend developers won't bother install nodejs at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this question too...

I copy the assets (CSS, javascript, images, fonts) from the dependencies into my app or themes assets directory then build from there.

My reasoning for this is that any images or fonts linked to the css file could break b/c of relative paths.

Still not sure if that is the 'right' way to do it.. it has just worked for me in the past.

Comment: You can override paths with variables, no need to copy them.